# i develop an app which is in production on play console. But when user download the app and try to open it throws an error App is not installed. How

Tags: android

i develop an app which is in production on play console. But when user download the app and try to open it throws an error App is not installed. I tried it to download the app in many device but every device show the same eror. This the first time when i am publish an app in playstore.

I am expecting to know what is the problem and how to solve it.